# What are the Red card requirements for Venezuelans?

Tags: visa, immigration, spain, refugees

I have heard that Spain has some "humanitarian visa" for people flying out of horrible countries like Venezuela… The name of that is "tarjeta roja" or red card. Does anyone can tell me what Venezuelans have to do to get that card?

Answer (score 3):

To request international protection in Spain an asylum seeker must present a formal application to the competent authorities. There are two main ways to apply for asylum: in the Spanish territory or at border controls. Asylum applications cannot be submitted through embassies or consular representations outside the Spanish territory.

If the application is declared admissible, the Ministry of Interior will have a period of six months to examine the request. However, in practice this period is usually longer. During this time, the applicant will receive new documentation certifying his or her status as asylum seeker, a red card (tarjeta roja).
https://www.asylumineurope.org/reports/country/spain/short-overview-asylum-procedure

Comment: does this mean that I need to fly to spain as a Tourist and then there apply?

Comment: Not necessarily - a ‘tarjeta roja’ is not a type of visa that you can apply for from outside Spanish territory, but you can arrive there by air, sea or land. This section https://www.asylumineurope.org/reports/country/spain/differential-treatment-specific-nationalities-procedure notes that at the end of 2018 there were over 28,000 pending asylum claims from Venezuelans